# Node js Login API with Passport js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm building an project witch having lots of API but I have login API too in this case I'm using passport local stratagy for it I followed this video [Node.js With Passport Authentication | Full Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k) But now while making API I haven't rendering page I want to send json respose that will says that password wrong or user not found but in local stratagy has only success redirect and failure redirect don't ay option to send json reponse Please suggest me a secure technique to do that also I'm verifing email is verified or not and user banned or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article https://medium.com/swlh/set-up-an-express-js-app-with-passport-js-and-mongodb-for-password-authentication-6ea05d95335c
It will cover from start to end of using passport.js login using local strategy.

Here is the repo of above code implementation
https://github.com/FBosler/fb-tutorial-social-login/tree/steps/3_backend_1